# Getting No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey). on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security, openssh

I am trying to connect to server using SSH and getting below error.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/etap_automation_user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/etap_automation_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/etap_automation_user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
rm: missing operand
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `openssl` needs to be updated on whatever machine the server is running on, as it's 6yrs out of date (1.1.1d is the [current version](https://www.openssl.org/) [FIPS compliant is is 2.0.16], released 2019.09.10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker

Your key file is broken or in an unsupported format.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said in his answer, the "missing begin marker" line means that one of your keys is missing the initial banner.

A private RSA key (for example "id_rsa") should begin with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and end with

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you are still stuck, I suggest you post the content of your .ssh directory so we can see the keys you have there and, if you have access to it, the relevant snipped of /var/log/auth.log (assuming you are trying to connect to a Linux box).

Comment: content of ssh directory is as mentioned in attached screenshot.

-rw------- 1  authorized_keys

-rw------- 1  authorized_keys_bu

-r-------- 1   etap_automation_user@172.31.26.54

-r-------- 1   id_rsa

-r-------- 1   id_rsa.pub

-rw------- 1  known_hosts

-rw------- 1  known_hosts.old

-rw-r--r-- 1  thorpubkey

-rw-r--r-- 1  thorpubkey.pub

Comment: So you have only one private key (id_rsa) that the ssh client can recognize even if you don't explicitly mention it via the "-i" option, and that key seems to have something wrong with it. Does the "id_rsa" file contain the markers I mentioned in my reply?

Comment: Yes it has markers as -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- which you have mentioned in the post

Comment: Jagjeet, you never confirmed that the private key was in the correct format. You might want to be more detailed and explicit to let other people understand what's going on.
Please edit your original post to include the full command line.
Do you have access to the server logs? Is is a Linux box?

Comment: I can see that you found out that the key was the problem. Would you mind closing this question picking the answer that helped you the most?